# Need advise for efficiency about Manipulating data on Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have three data, which are needed to be merged according to instructions given.

First data is 'Energy Indicators.xls', which is a list of [indicators of energy supply and renewable electricity production](https://hub.coursera-notebooks.org/user/jhegahdexndbnuwdkhikxw/notebooks/Energy%20Indicators.xls) from the United Nations for the year 2013, and should be put into a DataFrame with the variable name of 'energy'.

Before putting into a DataFrame, the footer and header information and first two columns must be excluded from the datafile since they are unnecessary.

Rest of column labels should be changed like:

```
['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']
```

Missing data should be reflected as np.NaN values.

Following list of countries must be renamed:

"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",

"United States of America": "United States",

"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",

"China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong".

There are also several countries with numbers and/or parenthesis in their name. They are needed to be removed too.

This part is done as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

energy = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls',skiprows=17,skip_footer=38
                 ,parse_cols =[2,3,4,5])
energy.columns = ['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita'
                         ,'% Renewable']
energy.set_index('Country',inplace=True)
energy.replace('...', np.nan,inplace=True)
energy.set_index(energy.index.str.replace('\s*\(.*?\)\s*','')
                             .str.replace('\d+',''),inplace=True)

energy.rename(index={"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
             "United States of America": "United States",
             "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
             "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"}
             ,inplace=True)
```

Next data is GDP data from the file 'world_bank.csv', which is a csv containing countries' GDP from 1960 to 2015 from [World Bank](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD).

Header must be skipped, and rename following list of countries must be renamed as follows:

"Korea, Rep.": "South Korea",

"Iran, Islamic Rep.": "Iran",

"Hong Kong SAR, China": "Hong Kong".

Code for this part is provided on the below.

```
GDP=pd.read_csv('world_bank.csv',skiprows=4)
GDP.replace({'Country Name': {'Korea, Rep.': 'South Korea', 
               'Iran, Islamic Rep.': 'Iran',
               'Hong Kong SAR, China': 'Hong Kong'}},inplace=True)
GDP.set_index('Country Name',inplace=True)
GDP.rename(index={'Country Name':'Country'},inplace=True)
```

Last data is 'scimagojr-3.xlsx', which ranks countries based on their journal contributions.
There is no additional work for manipulating them and code is written as follows:

```
ScimEn=pd.read_excel('scimagojr-3.xlsx') 
ScimEn.set_index('Country',inplace=True)
```

Joining the three datasets using the intersection of country names by using only the last 10 years (2006-2015) of GDP data and only the top 15 countries by Scimagojr 'Rank' (Rank 1 through 15).

The index of this DataFrame should be the name of the country, and the columns should be:

`['Rank', 'Documents', 'Citable documents', 'Citations', 'Self-citations', 'Citations per document', 'H index', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015']`.

This part is done as follows:

```
df=pd.merge(ScimEn.iloc[0:15],
   pd.merge(energy,GDP[['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011'
   ,'2012','2013','2014','2015']]
   ,left_index=True, right_index=True),left_index=True
   ,right_index=True)
```

So, The concern is that although it works, I need to find a more efficient approach for bigger future data sets. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: this is a well written question but is TOO LONG!  skipping to the end, it appears you are just asking how to do a 3-way merge more efficiently and there might or might not be a better way -- sometimes merges of big data are slow and there's not much you can do about it.  but if you want to have a good chance at receiving a helpful answer you need to vastly reduce this question to focus on the core of the issue (which here is just a 3-way merge as best I can see with a quick glance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you do a three way merge in one line of code:

```
df1 = data1.set_index('country')
df2 = data2.set_index('country')
df3 = data3.set_index('country')

new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)
```